# Values differences between days

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a SQL Server 2005 table titled "Journeys" as follows:

```
+---------------+
|   Journeys    |
+---------------+
| JourneyID     |
| PlateNumber   |
| DepartureDate |
| DepartureKM   |
| ArrivalDate   |
| ArrivalKM     |
+---------------+
```

The table contains the following sample data:

```
+------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| JOURNEYID  | PLATENUMBER  | DEPARTUREDATE  | DEPARTUREKM  | ARRIVALDATE  | ARRIVALKM |
+------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|         1  | ABC-123      | 01-01-2015     |       10000  | 01-02-2015   |     10200 |
|         2  | ABC-123      | 01-02-2015     |       10210  | 01-03-2015   |     10500 |
|         3  | ABC-123      | 01-03-2015     |       10500  | 01-04-2015   |     10650 |
|         4  | ABC-123      | 01-04-2015     |       10607  | 01-05-2015   |     10900 |
|         5  | XYZ-999      | 01-15-2015     |       30200  | 01-16-2015   |     30400 |
|         6  | XYZ-999      | 01-16-2015     |       30405  | 01-17-2015   |     30600 |
|         7  | XYZ-999      | 01-17-2015     |       30600  | 01-18-2015   |     30750 |
|         8  | XYZ-999      | 01-18-2015     |       30752  | 01-19-2015   |     30920 |
+------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I want to generate a query that returns a the following results with an extra column named 'KMDifference' which is the difference between 'ArrivalKM' from last day and 'DepartureKM' from today.

Desired results:

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| PlateNumber | DepartureDate | DepartureKM | ArrivalDate | ArrivalKM | KMDifference |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| ABC-123     | 01-01-2015    |       10000 | 01-02-2015  |     10200 |            0 |
| ABC-123     | 01-02-2015    |       10210 | 01-03-2015  |     10500 |           10 |
| ABC-123     | 01-03-2015    |       10500 | 01-04-2015  |     10650 |            0 |
| ABC-123     | 01-04-2015    |       10607 | 01-05-2015  |     10900 |            7 |
| XYZ-999     | 01-15-2015    |       30200 | 01-16-2015  |     30400 |            0 |
| XYZ-999     | 01-16-2015    |       30405 | 01-17-2015  |     30600 |            5 |
| XYZ-999     | 01-17-2015    |       30600 | 01-18-2015  |     30750 |            0 |
| XYZ-999     | 01-18-2015    |       30752 | 01-19-2015  |     30920 |            2 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

See this SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28abd

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you having an issue? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `CTE` based query in order to simulate `LAG` function available from SQL Server 2012 onwards:

```
;WITH Journeys_rn AS (
   SELECT JourneyID, PlateNumber, DepartureDate, DepartureKM, ArrivalDate, ArrivalKM,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PlateNumber ORDER BY DepartureDate) AS rn
   FROM Journeys
)
SELECT j1.PlateNumber, j1.DepartureDate, j1.DepartureKM,
       j1.ArrivalDate, j1.ArrivalKM,  
       j1.DepartureKM - ISNULL(j2.ArrivalKM, j1.DepartureKM) AS KMDifference
FROM Journeys_rn AS j1 
LEFT JOIN Journeys_rn AS j2 ON j1.rn = j2.rn+1 AND j1.PlateNumber = j2.PlateNumber
```

`j2.ArrivalKM` in the above query is the value from *previous* record. `ISNULL` is needed so that a 0 value is calculated for the *first* record of each group.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78251/2)

P.S. The sample data in the OP do not match with the sample data of the SQL Fiddle source also provided in the OP. So had to fix it in order to get the desired reult set.